# Counting results in SQLite, given query with functions

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

As you may (or may not) already know, SQLite does not provide information about total number of results from the query. One has to wrap the query in `SELECT count(*) FROM (original query);` in order to get row count.

This worked perfectly fine for me, until one of users created custom SQL function (you can define your own functions in SQLite) that does `INSERT` into another, unrelated table. Then he executes query:

```
SELECT customFunction() FROM primaryTable WHERE primaryKeyColumnId = 1;
```

The query returns always 1 row, that is certain. It turns out that `customFunction()` was called twice (and inserted to that other table 2 rows) and that's because my application called his query as usuall and then called `count(*)` on that query as a followup.

How to approach this problem? How to execute only the original query and still have a row count from SQLite?

I'm using SQLite (3.13.0) C API.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to remove such function calls from the query, or you cannot get the row count before actually having stepped through all the result rows.